# SQL for Dates with no ClosePrice for all companies

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server

I have a fact table where I have ClosePrice for Company Tickers and  TradingDates. I also have a dimCalendar table where all dates are there and a flag is maintained for Trading Holidays.

Somehow I need to have a new fact table or materialized view or something for reporting purposes where I need to have ClosePrice for every day including TradingHolidays.

ClosePrice for trading holidays should be previous trading day's close price for that CompanyTicker. Then I need to have another column for '5 day average Close Price'. For average calculation close price for trading days should only be included.

So, let's assume this is Current State.[State1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB9Qp.jpg)

And below is After joining with Calendar.

[image: Posting Image for dummy data since don't know how to attach excel]

I guess 1st step is to Left Join Calendar Table. That gives me 0 Stock price for missing Days.

```
select a.date as tdate, a.datekey, b.ticker, coalesce(b.ClosePrice,0)
from dimdates a left join 
    factStockDividendCommodity b
    on a.DateKey = b.datekey --and b.ticker = 'BP'
where (a.Datekey between 20180101 and 20181231 )
order by a.Date
```

Not Sure how I can get the Ticker and then Previous Trading Day's close price.

[image: Similar Requirement but not really I think]

Comment: Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Try to explain your problem so it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea is to generate the rows using a `cross join` and then fill in the values.  In your case, you probably want to take into account that stocks may not exist at all points in the past, so you only want this for the minimum observed date.

To fill in the date,you can use `lag(ignore nulls)` in standard SQL:

```
select d.date as tdate, d.datekey, t.ticker, 
       coalesce(fsdc.ClosePrice,
                lag(fsdc.ClosePrice ignore nulls) over (partition by t.ticker order by d.date) as ClosePrice
from dimdates d join
     (select ticker, min(datekey) as min_date
      from factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
      group by ticker
     ) t
     on d.datekey >= t.min_datekey left join
     factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
     on fsdc.ticker = t.ticker and
        fsdc.datekey = d.datekey
where d.Datekey between 20180101 and 20181231
order by d.Date;
```

Alas, many databases -- even those that support `lag()` -- do not support the `ignore nulls` option.  The best approach then depends on the database.  A correlated subquery is the most general method, but perhaps not the best from a performance perspective.

EDIT:

SQL Server does not support the `IGNORE NULLS` option. 
This is probably most easily handled using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select d.date as tdate, d.datekey, t.ticker, 
       fsdc.ClosePrice as ClosePrice
from dimdates d join
     (select ticker, min(datekey) as min_date
      from factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
      group by ticker
     ) t
     on d.datekey >= t.min_datekey outer apply
     (select top (1) fsdc.*
      from factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
      where fsdc.ticker = t.ticker and
            fsdc.datekey <= d.datekey
      order by fsdc.datekey desc
     ) fsdc
where d.Datekey between 20180101 and 20181231
order by d.Date;
```

However, because there are probably never more than 3 or 4 days without values in a row, a series of `lag()`s might be more efficient:

```
select d.date as tdate, d.datekey, t.ticker, 
       coalesce(fsdc.ClosePrice,
                lag(fsdc.ClosePrice, 1) over (partition by t.ticker order by d.date),
                lag(fsdc.ClosePrice, 2) over (partition by t.ticker order by d.date),
                lag(fsdc.ClosePrice, 3) over (partition by t.ticker order by d.date)
               ) as ClosePrice
from dimdates d join
     (select ticker, min(datekey) as min_date
      from factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
      group by ticker
     ) t
     on d.datekey >= t.min_datekey left join
     factStockDividendCommodity fsdc
     on fsdc.ticker = t.ticker and
        fsdc.datekey = d.datekey
where d.Datekey between 20180101 and 20181231
order by d.Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using SQL Server. I think the t query you meant to be  

    (select ticker, min(datekey) as min_datekey  
    from factStockDividendCommodity fsdc  
    group by ticker ) t     

But I get following error  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27  
Incorrect syntax near 'ignore'.  
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32  
Incorrect syntax near 't'.  
  
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Woww!! That is amazing. The Second Statement is running much faster than the First one. I will check maximum lag possible and adjust accordingly. This solves the first part of the puzzle.  Thank you so much!!  
  </br>  
How can we now do a 5 day Trading Average? We need to ignore the non-trading days in our calculation

Comment: I am trying with AVG(fsdc.ClosePrice ) OVER (ORDER BY d.date ASC ROWS 4 PRECEDING) as avgprice but not sure where to put this correctly...and then may be I need to again to similar Lag ??? MMMMM.....thinking and trying.....          Appreciate any help

Comment: @ITNube . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: I had Average also in the Title. Sorry if I asked 2 questions in 1 post. I will modify the title, accept this as a solution and post a new question for 5 day trading average.